# Parsing XML for sub children using using python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse the below XML to get the following data. There are multiple rules following, I have shared only one rule below. Is it possible to parse the XML for these values?

name from section header, rule id value, applied-to name, source names, source values, destination name, destination value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filteredfirewallConfiguration timestamp="1621338984151">
    <contextId>globalroot</contextId>
    <layer3Sections>
        <section id="asdfsdf" name="production" generationNumber="132" timestamp="1621930404081" managedBy="universalroot-0" tcpStrict="false" stateless="false" useSid="false" type="LAYER3">
            <rule id="1213213" disabled="false" logged="true" managedBy="universalroot-0">
                <name>From Conversion Server</name>
                <action>allow</action>
                <appliedToList>
                    <appliedTo>
                        <name>re-int-dx</name>
                        <value>universalwire</value>
                        <type>VirtualWire</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </appliedTo>
                    <appliedTo>
                        <name>re-ext-ap</name>
                        <value>universalwire</value>
                        <type>VirtualWire</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </appliedTo>
                </appliedToList>
                <sectionId>sfsdfafee</sectionId>
                <sources excluded="false">
                    <source>
                        <name>sdfsdf101</name>
                        <value>ipset-werfwefdc</value>
                        <type>IPSet</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                        <name>sdfsfdf102</name>
                        <value>ipset-4wsetgfreds</value>
                        <type>IPSet</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </source>
                </sources>
                <destinations excluded="false">
                    <destination>
                        <name>production-database-cluster</name>
                        <value>sg</value>
                        <type>SecurityGroup</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </destination>
                    <destination>
                        <name>newname</name>
                        <value></value>
                        <type>IPSet</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </destination>
                </destinations>
                <services>
                    <service>
                        <name>servicenwe</name>
                        <value>application-dgfsdfg</value>
                        <type>Application</type>
                        <isValid>true</isValid>
                    </service>
                </services>
                <direction>inout</direction>
                <packetType>any</packetType>
            </rule>
```

sofar, I have been able to get the section header only.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("out.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.find('./layer3Sections'):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

Comment: What did you try until now? And could you share your expected result?

Comment: I am able to get the complete section header with the below code. but struggling to get the rest of the details.
```
for child in root.find('./layer3Sections'):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```
the expected result is the values from below to export them to csv.

name from section header, rule id value, applied-to name, source names, source values, destination name, destination value